# Keyboard interrupts constraint layout guidelines

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, keyboard

When keyboard pops-up when focusing edit text, horizontal guidelines in my constraint layouts reads that layout as whole has additional height, they become more narrow. How to prevent keyboard from interrupting guide lines?

Comment: You'll have to share some code, otherwise it's hard to help you

Comment: I don't think it's needed, just regular horizontal guidelines, they change position when keyboard shows.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, your layout isn't resizing the way you want it to, when focusing an EditText. Android does this by default, but you can specify a different behavior, using the "windowSoftInputMode" attribute of your Activity, defined in the Manifest.xml file.

Here's an example:

```
<activity
    android:name="com.activites.MyActivity"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">
</activity>
```

More info about this here:
https://developer.android.com/training/keyboard-input/visibility.html